# Subsets of uniformly discrete sets are closed

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Suppose that $A$ is a countably infinite subset with the property that there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that if $a,b\in A$ and $a\neq b$, then $d(a,b)>\varepsilon$. Let me call such a set *uniformly discrete*.

I want to prove that if $B\subseteq A$, then $B$ is closed.

Indeed, if $y$ is in the closure of $B$, then there exists a sequence $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $B$ converging to $y$. This sequence must be eventually constant due to the fact that $A$ is separated. This is because there exists some $K_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb N$ such that $k>K_{\varepsilon}$ implies that $d(y_k,y)<\varepsilon/2$. By the triangle inequality, if $k,\ell>K_{\varepsilon}$, then
$$d(y_k,y_{\ell})\leq d(y_k,y)+d(y_{\ell},y)<\varepsilon,$$
so $y_k=y_{\ell}$ (otherwise $d(y_k,y_{\ell})>\varepsilon$ due to the fact that $A$ is separated—a contradiction). Let $\overline y$ denote this constant the members of the sequence $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are eventually equal to.

Then, for any $\xi>0$, one can pick $\ell\in\mathbb N$ so large that

- $y_{\ell}=\overline y$,
- $d(y_{\ell},y)<\xi$.

It follows that $d(y,\overline y)<\xi$. Since $\xi>0$ is arbitrary, $d(y,\overline y)=0$, or $y=\overline y\in B$. Therefore, $B$ contains its closure, so it is a closed set.

Is this correct? Thank you.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: The term you want is an [$\varepsilon$-packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delone_set). Talking about separated sets is confusing as this term already has a meaning.

Comment: @user2345215 Thank you for the reference. I changed the adjective to “uniformly discrete.”

Comment: @GenericNickname Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Fix $a\in X$, then the ball
$$
B(a,\varepsilon/2)=\{x\in X: d(x,a)<\varepsilon/2\}=\{a\}.
$$
But $B(a,\varepsilon/2)$ is open, and hence every singleton is open, and hence every subset of $X$ is open (since every set is the union of singletons, and arbitrary union of open sets is an open set).

But if every set is open, then every set is closed!

Comment: A caveat: $X$ should be changed to $A$ (note: $A$ is not necessarily equal to $X$), in which case you prove that the _relative_ topology on $A$ induced by the metric is the discrete topology.

Answer (score 1):

The closure argument works but can be simplified: so suppose $y \in \overline{B}$, and so there is a sequence $(y_n)$ from $B$ that converges to $y$. Your argument shows that $(y_n)$ is eventually constant. This means (the unique limit an eventually constant sequence converges to, is that constant, as limits are unique in metric spaces) that $y = y_k$ for some $k$, so $y \in B$ and you're done ($\overline{B} \subseteq B$).